# QRCode scanner prevent misuse on menu app

Tags: react-native, mobile, camera, expo, qr-code

So I'm working on a react native expo app ,which deals with touchless menu where a QRcode is placed on the table and you can scan it and start ordering in a restaurant ,I came across a scenario where the user can scan the QR code and go home and still able to place an order or if he makes a note of the scanned QR code via mobile camera he can again place an order without being in the restaurant .

So my point is how do I prevent a user from misusing the QR code ,what steps I should take in order to prevent this scenario from happening ,I searched various platforms and couldn't find a proper answer.

So I just need the workflow I don't need any code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way to implement a location restriction for a user is to get their permission to use their location, which in some cases a malicious user may be able to forge and still get access.

There could be monitors inside the restaurant to show a unique code which every user has to enter to get access to the menu, but again, that can cause more harm than good and be a hell to implement!

Comment: thanks for the reply ,Would geo location be accurate for 100 meters  ,to restrict based on location ?

Comment: In places where GPS signal is not obstructed by tall buildings and such, smartphones using GPS are accurate to about 5 meters

Comment: Based on GPS.gov "For example, GPS-enabled smartphones are typically accurate to within a 4.9 m (16 ft.) radius under open sky (view source at ION.org). However, their accuracy worsens near buildings, bridges, and trees. "